# Leverage Browser Caching OctoberCMS + NGINX

Tags: nginx, octobercms

I ran my site through a performance test website (gtmetrix.com) and it says I need to 'leverage browser caching'. In the OctoberCMS docs, it says to use the following in the config: https://octobercms.com/docs/setup/configuration#nginx-configuration

I added the following after the suggested Nginx configuration:

```
server {
    root /var/www/html/example;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;
    server_name example.com www.example.com;

    if ($host = www.example.com) {
        return 301 https://example.com$request_uri;
    }

    location / {
        #try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        rewrite ^/.*$ /index.php last;
    }

    location ~ ^/index.php {
            include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
    }

    # Whitelist
    ## Let October handle if static file not exists
    location ~ ^/favicon\.ico { try_files $uri /index.php; }
    location ~ ^/sitemap\.xml { try_files $uri /index.php; }
    location ~ ^/robots\.txt { try_files $uri /index.php; }
    location ~ ^/humans\.txt { try_files $uri /index.php; }

    ## Let nginx return 404 if static file not exists
    location ~ ^/storage/app/uploads/public { try_files $uri 404; }
    location ~ ^/storage/app/media { try_files $uri 404; }
    location ~ ^/storage/temp/public { try_files $uri 404; }

    location ~ ^/modules/.*/assets { try_files $uri 404; }
    location ~ ^/modules/.*/resources { try_files $uri 404; }
    location ~ ^/modules/.*/behaviors/.*/assets { try_files $uri 404; }
    location ~ ^/modules/.*/behaviors/.*/resources { try_files $uri 404; }
    location ~ ^/modules/.*/widgets/.*/assets { try_files $uri 404; }
    location ~ ^/modules/.*/widgets/.*/resources { try_files $uri 404; }
    location ~ ^/modules/.*/formwidgets/.*/assets { try_files $uri 404; }
    location ~ ^/modules/.*/formwidgets/.*/resources { try_files $uri 404; }
    location ~ ^/modules/.*/reportwidgets/.*/assets { try_files $uri 404; }
    location ~ ^/modules/.*/reportwidgets/.*/resources { try_files $uri 404; }

    location ~ ^/plugins/.*/.*/assets { try_files $uri 404; }
    location ~ ^/plugins/.*/.*/resources { try_files $uri 404; }
    location ~ ^/plugins/.*/.*/behaviors/.*/assets { try_files $uri 404; }
    location ~ ^/plugins/.*/.*/behaviors/.*/resources { try_files $uri 404; }
    location ~ ^/plugins/.*/.*/reportwidgets/.*/assets { try_files $uri 404; }
    location ~ ^/plugins/.*/.*/reportwidgets/.*/resources { try_files $uri 404; }
    location ~ ^/plugins/.*/.*/formwidgets/.*/assets { try_files $uri 404; }
    location ~ ^/plugins/.*/.*/formwidgets/.*/resources { try_files $uri 404; }
    location ~ ^/plugins/.*/.*/widgets/.*/assets { try_files $uri 404; }
    location ~ ^/plugins/.*/.*/widgets/.*/resources { try_files $uri 404; }

    location ~ ^/themes/.*/assets { try_files $uri 404; }
    location ~ ^/themes/.*/resources { try_files $uri 404; }

    #browser caching of static assets
    location ~*  \.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|ico|css|js)$ {
        expires 365d;
    }

    location ~*  \.(pdf)$ {
        expires 30d;
    }

    location ~ /\.ht {
            deny all;
    }

    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot
}
```

After a server restart, I am still getting the `leverage browser caching` flag. Am I configuring this wrong?

Comment: Can you please share your complete config?

Comment: Shared the full config.

Comment: Looks ok in my opinion

Answer (score 1):

I found a working solution. https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-implement-browser-caching-with-nginx-s-header-module-on-ubuntu-16-04

```
# Expires map
map $sent_http_content_type $expires {
    default                    off;
    text/html                  epoch;
    text/css                   max;
    application/javascript     max;
    ~image/                    max;
}

server {
    ...

    expires $expires;
    ...
}
```